# understanding container template parameter of `std::stack`

Tags: c++, stl, stack

What exactly does the second template parameter of `std::stack` represent? For example, in the following code, what does `std::vector<int>` imply?

```
std::stack<int, std::vector<int>> fourth(myvector);
```

Comment: Check out the C++ reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack

Comment: @FRob [en.cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) is the better reference IMHO.

Comment: @YashasSamaga Also note `std::stack<int,std::vector<int> > fourth (myvector);` just takes a copy of `myvector` for initialization, not a reference. Further (`push()`,`pop()`) operations on `fourth` won't be reflected in `myvector`, neither would any operations on `myvector` be reflected in `fourth`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::vector<int>
```

specifies the container used by `std::stack<int>` to store the values internally.

The template signature of `std::stack` is

```
template<
    class T,
    class Container = std::deque<T>
> class stack;
```

Check the explanations on the `Container` template parameter [**here**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) please.

You can specify container classes that fulfil the requirements of a [Sequence Container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/SequenceContainer) there. The default container type is [`std::deque<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque), if you omit the template parameter specification.

---

**NOTE:**

To avoid any misconceptions from your side, about the *wrapping* done by `std::stack<>` around these container instances:

```
std::stack<int,std::vector<int> > fourth (myvector);
```

Matches the [`explicit stack( const Container& cont );`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/stack) constructor signature, which

> 1) Copy-constructs the underlying container `c` with the contents of `cont`. This is also the default constructor (until C++11)

Thus, the `myvector` and the `fourth` instances are independent after the construction of `fourth`. Manipulating either of them does not affect the other.
The `std::vector<int>` instance used by `fourth` is managed internally.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the template parameters for `std::stack`:

```
template< class T, class Container = std::deque<T>> class stack;
```

`std::stack` is a *container adapter* and it default wraps `std::deque`. This code changing it so that `fourth` wraps an `std::vector` instead.

Comment: The standard term is *container adapter*.

Comment: How do I choose which wrapper to use in a stack?

Comment: @YashasSamaga: Use the default until/unless you know you need otherwise. Also stack is the wrapper, not the thing it wraps ;p